# Created a batch apex to send birthdaynotificationtemplate to an account(customer)

Tags: schedulebatch

Created a batch apex to send birthday notification template to an account(customer). First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid cross reference id: []

```
global class BirthdayNotificationBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>,schedulable{

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        integer month=system.today().month();
       // integer day=system.today().day();
        string  query ='select id,DateOfBirth__c,PersonEmail,lastname,firstname from account where  CALENDAR_MONTH(DateOfBirth__c)= :month';      


        //This is query for getting records
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<account> AllaccountRecords){
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
        List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
        Id templateId =  [select id, name from EmailTemplate where developername = 'BirthdayNotificationTemplates'].id;
        for(account acc : AllaccountRecords){
            if(acc.DateOfBirth__c.day() == system.today().day()){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail =

                new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // Who you are sending the email to

            mail.setTargetObjectId(acc.id);



            // The email template ID used for the email

            mail.setTemplateId('00X30000001GLJj');



            mail.setWhatId(acc.id);   

            mail.setBccSender(false);

            mail.setUseSignature(false);

           // mail.setReplyTo('recruiting@acme.com');

            mail.setSenderDisplayName('Wishes');

            mail.setSaveAsActivity(false); 


            mails.add(mail);





        }
        }
        if(mails.size() > 0){
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
        }
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

    }
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
        BirthdayNotificationBatchClass b1 = new BirthdayNotificationBatchClass();
        ID batchprocessid = Database.executeBatch(b1,500);
    }

}
```

Comment: I would say, that the problem is with this part (mail.setTemplateId('00X30000001GLJj');), can you make sure that this is the right id? maybe also, try comment out this part to make sure.

Comment: you have code that queries the templateId based on templateName (good) but then ignore this in lieu of a hard-coded id (bad)